# Parse error from OWL validator

Tags: validation, parsing, owl, ontology

In fact, I realized  ontology through OWLApi. Then I recovered a file .owl. I tried later to check the syntax of OWL ontology through the OWL Validator: http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/validator/. It returned more mistake which I can not understanding.
 I joined you firstly my ontology then the appeared errors.
 Thank you in advance for your help

```xml
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
 xml:base="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl"
 xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
 xmlns:p1="#"
 xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">



<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Object Properties
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->




<!-- #kindOf -->

<ObjectProperty rdf:about="#kindOf"/>



<!-- #sub-topicOf -->

<ObjectProperty rdf:about="#sub-topicOf"/>



<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Classes
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->




<!-- #OWLThing -->

<Class rdf:about="#OWLThing"/>



<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Individuals
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->




<!-- #ATTACKERS -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#ATTACKERS">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #AUTHENTICATION -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#AUTHENTICATION">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
    <p1:kindOf rdf:resource="#validation"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #CLUSTERING -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#CLUSTERING">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #CRYPTOGRAPHY -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#CRYPTOGRAPHY">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
    <p1:sub-topicOf rdf:resource="#SECURITY"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #DETECTION -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#DETECTION">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #EMBEDDING -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#EMBEDDING">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #ENCRYPTION -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#ENCRYPTION">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
    <p1:kindOf rdf:resource="#CRYPTOGRAPHY"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #LEARNING -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#LEARNING">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
    <p1:kindOf rdf:resource="#education"/>
    <p1:sub-topicOf rdf:resource="#ARTIFICIAL INTELLIGENCE"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #ONTOLOGY -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#ONTOLOGY">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #SECURITY -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#SECURITY">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #WATERMARKING -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#WATERMARKING">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
    <p1:sub-topicOf rdf:resource="#SECURITY"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #WAVELET -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#WAVELET">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #compression -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#compression">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
    <p1:kindOf rdf:resource="#ENCRYPTION"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #computing -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#computing">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #education -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#education">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #management -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#management">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #system -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#system">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #validation -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#validation">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #ABSTRACTING METHODS -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#ABSTRACTING METHODS">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #APPLICATION AND EXPERT SYSTEMS -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#APPLICATION AND EXPERT SYSTEMS">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
    <p1:sub-topicOf rdf:resource="#ARTIFICIAL INTELLIGENCE"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #ARTIFICIAL INTELLIGENCE -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#ARTIFICIAL INTELLIGENCE">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
    <p1:kindOf rdf:resource="#computing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #CONCEPTS LEARNING -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#CONCEPTS LEARNING">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #DATABASE MANAGEMENT -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#DATABASE MANAGEMENT">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
    <p1:kindOf rdf:resource="#management"/>
    <p1:sub-topicOf rdf:resource="#INFORMATION SYSTEMS"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #IMAGE DATABASE -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#IMAGE DATABASE">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #INDEXING METHOD -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#INDEXING METHOD">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #INFORMATION FILTERING -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#INFORMATION FILTERING">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #INFORMATION SOURCE -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#INFORMATION SOURCE">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #INFORMATION SYSTEMS -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#INFORMATION SYSTEMS">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
    <p1:kindOf rdf:resource="#system"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #INFORMATION STORAGE AND RETRIEVAL -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#INFORMATION STORAGE AND RETRIEVAL">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
    <p1:sub-topicOf rdf:resource="#INFORMATION SYSTEMS"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #KNOWLEDGE REPRESENTATION FORMALISMS AND METHODS -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#KNOWLEDGE REPRESENTATION FORMALISMS AND METHODS">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
    <p1:sub-topicOf rdf:resource="#ARTIFICIAL INTELLIGENCE"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #LINGUISTIC PROCESSING -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#LINGUISTIC PROCESSING">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #MOBILE AGENT -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#MOBILE AGENT">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #MULTI-AGENT SYSTEM -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#MULTI-AGENT SYSTEM">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #NATURAL LANGUAGE PROCESSING -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#NATURAL LANGUAGE PROCESSING">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
    <p1:sub-topicOf rdf:resource="#ARTIFICIAL INTELLIGENCE"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #NETWORK SECURITY -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#NETWORK SECURITY">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
    <p1:sub-topicOf rdf:resource="#SECURITY"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #REPRESENTATION LANGUAGE -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#REPRESENTATION LANGUAGE">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #SCIENTIFIC DATABASE -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#SCIENTIFIC DATABASE">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #SEARCH PROCESS -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#SEARCH PROCESS">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #SEMANTIC NETWORK -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#SEMANTIC NETWORK">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>



<!-- #SPEECH RECOGNITION AND SYNTHESIS -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="#SPEECH RECOGNITION AND SYNTHESIS">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#OWLThing"/>
</NamedIndividual>
```

Errors :

```
org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.UnparsableOntologyException: Problem parsing string:ontology405
```

Could not parse ontology.  Either a suitable parser could not be found, or parsing failed.  See parser logs below for explanation.
The following parsers were tried:

1) RDFXMLParser
2) OWLXMLParser
3) OWLFunctionalSyntaxOWLParser
4) TurtleOntologyParser
5) OWLOBOParser
6) KRSS2OWLParser
7) ManchesterOWLSyntaxOntologyParser

Detailed logs:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Parser: RDFXMLParser
org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.syntax.RDFParserException: [line=126:column=66] IRI '#ARTIFICIAL INTELLIGENCE' cannot be resolved against curent base IRI http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Parser: OWLXMLParser
Attribute not found: IRI (Line 24)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Parser: OWLFunctionalSyntaxOWLParser
Encountered " <ERROR> "< "" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting:
    "Ontology" ...
     (Line 0)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Parser: TurtleOntologyParser
uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.turtle.parser.ParseException: Encountered "" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting one of:


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Parser: OWLOBOParser
org.coode.owlapi.obo.parser.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 8, column 5.  Encountered: "\r" (13), after : ""

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Parser: KRSS2OWLParser
de.uulm.ecs.ai.owlapi.krssparser.ParseException: Encountered " ">" "<rdf:RDF xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#\"\r\n     xml:base=\"http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl\"\r\n     xmlns:rdfs=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#\"\r\n     xmlns:p1=\"#\"\r\n     xmlns:owl=\"http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#\"\r\n     xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#\"\r\n     xmlns:rdf=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#\"> "" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting:
    <EOF> 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Parser: ManchesterOWLSyntaxOntologyParser
Encountered '<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"' at line 1 column 1.  Expected either 'Ontology:' or 'Prefix:' (Line 1)


    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.ParsableOWLOntologyFactory.loadOWLOntology(ParsableOWLOntologyFactory.java:236)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:827)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:773)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.validator.Validator.doValidation(Validator.java:101)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.validator.Validator.doPost(Validator.java:85)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the RDF/XML serialization of the RDF representation of an OWL ontology, so while the validator attempts to use a bunch of different parsers, the only error message you should really be concerned with is

```
Parser: RDFXMLParser
org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.syntax.RDFParserException: [line=126:column=66] IRI '#ARTIFICIAL INTELLIGENCE' cannot be resolved against curent base IRI http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl
```

Offhand, I expect that this is because there's a space in `#ARTIFICIAL INTELLIGENCE`, and spaces are not allowed in URIs, so it's not going to be possible to resolve that against the base.  I think you need to remove the space, or replace the space with something else.

Also, you shouldn't be using `http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl` as your base, because if you'll end up with URIs like

```
http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#ARTIFICIAL_INTELLIGENCE
```

and you shouldn't be defining new URIs in the OWL namespace.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. In fact I changed all concept with space and then the error is became: `Use of non-absolute IRI` for all element in the ontology I know so that the cause of that is what you have mentionned that I shouldn't be using http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl as my base. But what I have to do to change it?? because it's automatically generated by OWL API

Comment: In general, you should be specifying absolute URIs when you create your ontology, and not having an API auto-generate them for you.  Have a look at the OWL API documentation examples to see how you can create entities with absolute URIs.

Comment: @user3503945 Regarding the generation, how did you create the ontology? It looks like it was created using the OWL namespace as ontology IRI, and each class created with IRI.create("#classname"). If you are unsure about this, please post the code here or as a question on the OWLAPI GitHub website (or on the OWLAPI mailing list)